# Nested LEFT OUTER JOINS takes too long compared to programmatical solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an SQL query generated by Entity Framework that contains a two level nested LEFT OUTER JOIN on tables TableA, TableB and TableC1 and TableC2 with the following foreign key relations as the arrows indicate.

```
TableA->TableB->TableC1
              ->TableC2
```

TableA contains 1000 rows, and all other tables contain around 100000 rows
The SQL statement looks something like this:

```
select * from TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.Id = B.TableAId
  LEFT JOIN TableC1 C1 on B.Id = C1.TableBId
  LEFT JOIN TableC2 C2 on B.Id = C2.TableBId
```

When SQL is executed on Microsoft SQL Server, it takes around 30 seconds.
However, if I do a select of each table and retrieve the rows as lists in memory and join them programmatically in C#, it takes 3 seconds or so.
Can anyone give any indication of why sql server is so slow?

Thanks

Comment: Share the query and the execution plan that is generated by the EF query.

Comment: Does the join field(s) have an appropriate index?

Comment: All foreign key relations are between indexes in the tables. So I assume they are correctly indexed.

Comment: Show the execution plan.

Comment: I just edited my question with an example of how the query looks.

Comment: Joining C1 and C2 will produce a cross join between those subsets. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: There can be varchar / nvarchar conversion issues if you do not declare your column types in EF mapping. I do not know your column types, just an information for you.

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Assuming they are correctly indexed does not mean they are. For them to be "correctly indexed" for this query the index would have to contain all the columns due to the SELECT *,I bet they don't. Capture the EF query in something like profiler and share the execution plan

Comment: The difference is how much data you fetch. By your query, you take SELECT * from everything, which will duplicate a lot of data, taking a lot of memory. Probably that's what taking the time. When you just read the tables by themselves, you avoid the duplication (i guess), since you probably don't select all columns in EF.

Comment: But why does SQL not just retrieve all the tables in mention and link them together using the foreign key relations, without having all columns as part of the index? If I can do that in code quite fast, I assume SQL server could do that too

Comment: But I do select all the columns in EF for each table.

Comment: What is the best way to share the execution plan? Is it in xml format, and can I upload it to this Stack overflow post?

Comment: Post the plan using the link Dan provided above. The linked page has instructions. Then update your original post with a link to the uploaded plan.

Comment: Your query appears to have multiple independent one-to-many joins - `TableB` to `TableC1` and `TableB` to `TableC2`. This will create a cartesian product of the joins. For example, if for a given `B.Id`, there are 10 matching `TableC1` rows and 20 matching `TableC2` rows, the result will include 200 rows for that particular `B.Id` value. Your logic to "join them programmatically in C#" might be managing these joins differently. Perhaps you are aggregating `TableC1` data separately from `TableC2`. One almost sure sign of such a problem is resorting to `DISTINCT` to eliminate unexpected dups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use joins in SQL you create something called a Cartesian Product.

For example, if I have 2 tables, Table A and Table B, Table A has 10 rows and each row has 10 Table B references:

If I load these 2 tables separately, I am loading 110 rows. 10 rows from table A, and 100 rows from table B.

If I JOIN these tables I am loading 100 rows, **however**, those hundred rows each represent the combine data of both tables. If Table A has 10 columns, and Table B has 20 columns, the total data read loading the tables separately would be 10x10 + 100x20 or 2100 columns worth of data.  With a JOIN, I am loading 30x100 or 3000 columns worth of data.  That's not a huge difference, but it compounds as I join more tables.

If each Table B has a Table C with an average of 5 rows and 10 columns, loaded separately that would add 5000 (500x10) or now 7600 columns worth of data. When Joined, that becomes 3000x5x10, or 150,000 columns worth of total data being loaded into memory or sifted through.  You should see how this can and does snowball quite quickly if you start doing SELECT * FROM ... with Joins.

When EF goes to build a query where you are loading entity graphs (related entities) the resulting query will often use JOINs resulting in these Cartesian results that it loads, then sifts through to build the resulting object graph, condensing the results back down into the 10 A's with 10 B's and 5 C's, etc. But it still takes memory and time to chew through all of that flattened resulting data. EF Core can offer query splitting to essentially execute more like what your counter-comparison was, loading the related tables separately to piece together, greatly reducing the total amount of data being read.

Ultimately to improve performance of queries generated by EF:

1. Use `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo` to select just the values from the related tables, rather than loading Entities /w `Include` to eager load related entities when reading "sets" of entities like search results. Load entities /w `Include` for single entities like when updating one.
2. Ensure that when querying the above data, inspect the execution plans for index suggestions.
3. If you do need to load large amounts of related data, consider use query splitting.

Comment: I think you are right. I am getting around 1.3 million rows back which actually contain a lot of duplicate values, from TableA. Will settle with the solution I found reading the tables one by one and doing a join programmatically

Comment: @JihadHaddad I believe the workaround you are using is pretty much the same thing that Entity Framework does automatically for you when you tell it to use query splitting.

Comment: Yes, query splitting will attempt to generate queries for the individual tables then link them up. Using Projection /w `Select` won't eliminate the Cartesian behaviour of the joins, but it can drastically reduce the size of the resulting data. Often developers will default to loading lists of Entities then eager-load *every* associated 1-to-many relationship because "lazy loading is bad", but end up with absolutely massive resultsets and wonder why EF is taking so long to return "just" x# of rows. :)

Comment: Worth noting that lazy-loading acts like query splitting except it executes on a row-by-row basis so it should be treated as a failsafe, and not relied on. With query splitting EF will query the associated tables to get all associated rows. Lazy loading with query the associated tables once for *each* parent row one at a time as the child collections are accessed. (Potentially a LOT of individual queries being sent to the DB and waited for)

Comment: @GendoIkari Wow I did not know this feature existed. I tried it and it works, and I think you are right that it probably does the same as I do. However, my manual join was 25% faster. Probably because I create dictionaries based on the keys I am joining on. Maybe EF is less efficient with respect to this